# Give role to user for application registred in fiware

Tags: fiware

I have done a application which I have registred in fiware, this application only have one  authorized user to use. I want to authorize more users with new roles to they can use it.
I am trying to give a role for an user without use the graphical interface whit keystone api, but nothing works. I am looking for in a lot of pages but I don´t find nothing. I find this page https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/REST-API only, where I saw Roles API. I have  tried to use, but it didn´t work.

If I use,
PUT /OS-ROLES/users/$user_id/applications/$application_id/roles/$role_id

Result,
{"error": {"message": "You are not authorized to perform the requested action: identity:add_role_to_user_default_org", "code": 403, "title": "Forbidden"}}

I don´t understand the result because I am the owner of the application. How I can solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is new documentation for the API in apiary with examples.
You can find the whole API documented [here](http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/)
And that specific endpoint documented [here](http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/#reference/keystone-extensions/role-user-relationship/assign-a-role-to-a-user)

If after following the new documentation you still have the same issue, let me know. You can also use the [github issue tracker](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/issues)

The github wiki is deprecated, don't use it anymore.